# How Can I Make Text Blinking On Canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
flag=True
win=tk.Tk()
def function():
    global flag
    if flag:
        canvas.create_text(134,26,fill="black",font="Times 26 bold",text="Blinking...")
    flag=not(flag)
canvas=tk.Canvas(win)
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"images.png")
canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=tk.NW,image=img)
canvas.pack()
btn=tk.Button(win,text="Click Me To Blink...",command=function)
btn.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

How Can I Make Text Blinking On Canvas ?
I Tried Creating A Variable **flag** And :

```
if flag:
     canvas.create_text(134,26,fill="black",font="Times 26 bold",text="Blinking...")
flag=not(flag)
```

But It Didn't Worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.after(...)` to call `function()` periodically and then toggle the state of the canvas text item (which should be created outside `function()`) between "normal" and "hidden" to simulate blinking effect:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

def function(show=False):
    btn.config(state="disabled")
    canvas.itemconfig(text, state="normal" if show else "hidden")
    canvas.after(200, function, not show) # change 200 to other value to adjust the blinking speed

win = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(win)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=r"images.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=img)

text = canvas.create_text(134, 26, fill="black", font="Times 26 bold", text="Blinking...")

btn = tk.Button(win, text="Click Me To Blink...", command=function)
btn.pack()

win.mainloop()
```